# Birthday problem, number of people for probability greater than $2/3$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> There are $n$ people in a lecture room. Their birthdays are independent random variables, and each person's birthday is equallly likely to be any of the 365 days of the year. By using the bound $1-x\le e^{-x}$ for $0\le x \le 1$, prove that if $n\ge 29$ then the probability that at least two people have the same birthday is at least $2/3$ **Hint:** In calculations, you may take $\sqrt{1+8\times 365 \log 3}=56.6$

I have solved this problem already by the conventional method,
$$1-P(X)=1\times(1-\frac{1}{365})\times...\times(1-\frac{n-1}{365})$$
then I use their bound
$$ \le e^{-1/365}\times...\times e^{-\frac{n-1}{365}}$$
and simplify you get, for $n\ge 29$, (I plugged in $n=29$)
$$1-P(X)\le e^{-406/365}$$

Now I take logs

$$\begin{aligned} \log (1-P(X))  &\le -(1+\frac{41}{365})\\ 
&\le -(1+\frac{36.5}{365}) \\
&= -1.1
\end{aligned}$$

and I happened to know $1.1$ is an upper bound for $\log 3$ so I'm done. However, I fail to see where in that I could have used the hint(And presumably the way I was supposed to do it was different). I think I have something to learn from seeing the way they wanted, so I am asking here in hopes that someone will see what they are getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know, $\frac {(56.6)^2-1}{8}=400.32$. So from  the hint, it is clear that, we can take:
$$3=e^{\frac {400.32}{365}}$$
so that $$\frac 13=e^{\frac {-400.32}{365}}>e^{\frac {-406}{365}}$$
This means that-
$$1-P(X)\leq e^{\frac {-406}{365}}<\frac 13$$
which means that $P(X)>\frac 23$ as required.